# Adding class to fancybox image pop up

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need to use a slightly different implementation of fancybox in 2 different places on my site.

One utilises a group of images and one just a single image.

I have added some styling to the overlay to achieve the styling I need to with the image group, however I do not need the additional styling with the single image as it pads the bottom of the white "frame" to create space for the navigation to sit. This just appears as empty white space in the single image which I need to remove.

Is there a way to send a class to the overlay via the image link for the single images so I can remove this white space?

```
<a href="/assets/Uploads/_resampled/croppedimage640480-site.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img src="/assets/Uploads/_resampled/croppedimage181118-site.jpg" alt="site">
</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using fancybox v2.x add this option

```
beforeShow : function(){
 $(".fancybox-inner").find("img").addClass("newClass");
}
```

it will add the `newClass` to the image (`img` tag) inside the fancybox

Just in case, if using fancybox v1.3.4 add

```
"onComplete": function(){
 $("#fancybox-content").find("img").addClass("newClass");
}
```

Comment: If you using older fancybox version, change "beforeShow" to "onStart"

Comment: @Footniko : wrong. `onStart : Will be called right before attempting to load the content` so you cannot add a class to an element that doesn't exist in DOM http://jsfiddle.net/Y8YhF/ The correct callback is `onComplete`

Comment: @JFK: Oh, yes. You are right. But you can change or add class for existing element with "beforeShow".

Comment: @Footniko : that is exactly what's written in the answer ;) ... still wondering how productive is this conversation!?!?